# Im representing electric field and im very close to the result i want, but i have to make 16 posibilities for rotation and i dont know exactly how

Tags: javascript, physics, trigonometry

Well, first of all, i have 3 canvas that are arrows(green,blue,white), the green one represent the electric line that is generated for the green charge, the same for the blue and the white arrow is the resultant vector. I have the page uploaded to github, this is the url: https://mauriciolapi.github.io/proyectoFisica/

I have 16 posibilities for the rotation:
[image]

The posibilities 13,14,15,16 are the easy ones, but the others i dont have any idea how to make it work

```
Javascript:
```

```
    let angle1;
    let angle2;

    let e1x;
    let e1y;
    let e2x;
    let e2y;

    let eRx;
    let eRy;

    let resultantAngle;

    if(q1Value && q2Value > 0){

        canvas1.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo1}deg)`;
        canvas2.style.transform = `rotate(${positivo2}deg)`;

        if(positivo1 > 0 && positivo1 < 90){
            angle1 = positivo1;
        }
        if(positivo1 > 90 && positivo1 < 180){
            angle1 = 180 - positivo1;
        }
        if(positivo1 > 180 && positivo1 < 270){
            angle1 = positivo1 - 180;
        }
        if(positivo1 > 270 && positivo1 < 360){
            angle1 = 360 - positivo1;
        }
        
        if(positivo2 > 0 && positivo2 < 90){
            angle2 = positivo2;
        }
        if(positivo2 > 90 && positivo2 < 180){
            angle2 = 180 - positivo2;
        }
        if(positivo2 > 180 && positivo2 < 270){
            angle2 = positivo2 - 180;
        }
        if(positivo2 > 270 && positivo2 < 360){
            angle2 = 360 - positivo2;
        }

        e1x = e1*Math.cos(angle1*Math.PI/180);
        e1y = e1*Math.sin(angle1*Math.PI/180);
        e2x = e2*Math.cos(angle2*Math.PI/180);
        e2y = e2*Math.sin(angle2*Math.PI/180);

        eRx = e1x + e2x;
        eRy = e1y + e2y;

        let resultant = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(eRx,2)+Math.pow(eRy,2));

        let tanAlpha = eRy/eRx;
        let alpha = (Math.atan(tanAlpha) * 180 / Math.PI);

        //13
        if((positivo1 && positivo2 > 0) && (positivo1 && positivo2 < 90)){ 
            resultantAngle = alpha;
        }
        //14
        if((positivo1 && positivo2 > 90) && (positivo1 && positivo2 < 180)){ 
            resultantAngle = 180 - alpha;
        }
        //15
        if((positivo1 && positivo2 > 180) && (positivo1 && positivo2 < 270)){ 
            resultantAngle = alpha - 180;
        }
        //16
        if((positivo1 && positivo2 > 270) && (positivo1 && positivo2 < 360)){ 
            resultantAngle = 360 - alpha;
        }
        

        //1
        if((positivo1 > 0 && positivo1 < 90) && (positivo2 > 90 && positivo2 < 180)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        //2
        if((positivo1 > 0 && positivo1 < 90) && (positivo2 > 180 && positivo2 <270)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        //3
        if((positivo1 > 0 && positivo1 < 90) && (positivo2 > 270 && positivo2 < 360)){
            resultantAngle
        }

        //4
        if((positivo1 > 90 && positivo1 < 180) && (positivo2 > 0 && positivo2 < 90)){
            resultantAngle
        }

        //5
        if((positivo1 > 90 && positivo1 < 180) && (positivo2 > 180 && positivo2 < 270)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        //6
        if((positivo1 > 90 && positivo1 < 180) && (positivo2 > 270 && positivo2 < 360)){
            resultantAngle
        }

        //7
        if((positivo1 > 180 && positivo1 < 270) && (positivo2 > 0 && positivo2 < 90)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        //8
        if((positivo1 > 180 && positivo1 < 270) && (positivo2 > 90 && positivo2 < 180)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        //9
        if((positivo1 > 180 && positivo1 < 270) && (positivo2 > 270 && positivo2 < 360)){
            resultantAngle
        }

        //10
        if((positivo1 > 270 && positivo1 < 360) && (positivo2 > 0 && positivo2 < 90)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        //11
        if((positivo1 > 270 && positivo1 < 360) && (positivo2 > 90 && positivo2 < 180)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        //12
        if((positivo1 > 270 && positivo1 < 360) && (positivo2 > 180 && positivo2 < 270)){
            resultantAngle
        }
        canvas3.style.transform = `rotate(${resultantAngle}deg)`
        
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[same green arrow]

```
setg1 : 1-2-3-13
setg2 : 4-5-6-14
setg3 : 7-8-9-15
setg4 : 10-11-12-16
```

[reflection of same blue arrow]

```
setb1{} : 1-3,4-5,6-14,2-13,3-8,7-15,8-9,10-12,11-16*
*11-16 should be the pair.. but the gfx diagree
```

[same blue arrow]

```
setb2{} : 4-10,5-12 (the only pairs i can c)
```

take away : patterns (code) the green arrow n blow arrow separately : draw as separate layers.

That should do. Pls share if it doesn't work/understandable..